# Is there a shortcut to construct Derived Class object using Base Class object

Tags: java, oop

I have a Base Class object containing all required fields. On the basis of a field , i need to return respective Derived Objects with all information from the base object duly filled.

I have a base class with field 1 , field 2. Now I want a way to pass back a derived object with all base class information in that.

I don;t think i can cast it to Derived Object. I can do it by passing a Base class object to the constructor and then copying individual elements to the new object.

IS there any shortcut ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will either need to copy over all the fields (you can automate this using Reflection but I would recommend just writing the code yourself). Alternatively you can get rid of the inheritance and use composition instead, which may or may not be an acceptable solution in your case.

What you could do is implement a copy constructor:

```
class Base {
  public Base() { } // Existing constructors

  public Base(Base other) {
    this.a = other.a;
    this.b = other.b;
    // ...
  }
}
```

and call it from the derived class constructors:

```
class Derived : Base {
  public Derived(Base template) { 
    super(template);

    // Initialize specific fields
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the Base and Derived Class and even not sure if I can even add a new constructor. What I understand from your answer is that i can only create a Factory method to construct derived object using members of Base Class.